# Finder wont respond on every restart attempt

Tags: finder, applications, macos, restart

Starting recently, every time I try to restart my laptop (MacBook Pro 15-inch, Mid 2012) everything exits fine, the menu bar disappears, but then finder won't quit.  If I open the dock and right-click it, it says 'application not responding'.  Clicking 'relaunch' doesn't seem to do anything.  The only thing that seems to work is holding down the power-button to force a shutdown, or doing Cmd+cntl+Power to force a restart*.

I tried booting in safe mode, and trying to restart there -- but I have the same problem.

Has anyone had this problem before?

OSX El Capitan 10.11.1

*This forces restart doesn't allow updates to be installed.

Comment: How long did you leave it before getting bored? 5 mins, I'd give it longer; overnight, fair play, something definitely awry ;) I'd try a safe boot & see if it gives an easy fix. Also test on a different [new, empty] account.

Comment: @Tetsujin, about 15 minutes - and, as I said, safe-mode didn't help.  I'll try a new account.

Comment: ah, sorry, reading too quickly, I totally missed the safe mode bit, my bad.